Connection Aborted on Wordpress API using Python requests
I generate blog content using Python, and I use WordPress REST API to automatically post it to my website. Until last night it was OK. But this morning, I got this
RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    499 
    500         except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:
--> 501             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    502 
    503         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

This is my Python code
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Set your username, password, and the hostname
username = MY_USERNAME
password = MY_PASSWORD
hostname = 'https://worldbestreview.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users'

# Perform a GET request with HTTP Basic Authentication
response = requests.get(hostname, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), params={'context': 'edit'})

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request successful!")
    # Print the content of the response (e.g., the data returned by the server)
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve data. Status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)

I tried with suggestion from other threads using fake headers, but it also does not work
import requests

hostname = 'https://worldbestreview.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users'

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    }
)

response = requests.get(hostname, headers=headers)

I remember installing some plugins (Rank Math SEO and Google Site Kit) before doing this. Is it related to the plugins?
I tried with curl and I got this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<title> 403 Forbidden
</title><style>@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{background-color:#000!important}}</style></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">403</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Forbidden
</h2>
<p>Access to this resource on the server is denied!</p>
</div></div></body></html>

Please help

Found the solution. Not sure why, but the authentication changed to basic authentication. Previously I can use application password (different with login password). But now strangely I cannot use the application password. I can now upload post using my user password
